# Why do I need a local master branch?

Tags: git, github

Our team is using git for quite some time, but still this thing escapes me. I'm constantly getting conflicts with my files that have been merged earlier, and vacuous diffs with the files modified by other team members. Usually, it happens in my branch merged earlier, and it is quite laborious to resolve these issues to get clean mergereq...

Therefore, I'm trying to simplify the development process as much as possible, to have it nuisance-error-resilient as SVN. Can I have one local branch sourced from origin/master which I merge every week? What do I need to do to keep it not stale, is egit pull just enough? Or do I have to dance through

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout my_branch
git merge master
```

every time? The first command obviously creates local master, which answers my question in the title, but why egit pull wouldn't be just enough?

Comment: Do you generally want to have one branch or do you use a flow with multiple branches?

Comment: If I abandon my branch after merge, I don't experience this problem. Creating new branch every time is a hassle (admittedly, lesser than resolving conflicts).

Comment: `git pull` is basically `git fetch` and `git merge origin/master`. If you want to just have one single branch, you can use your local master branch for local development and then do a `git pull --rebase`, which is basically the same as `git fetch` and `git rebase origin/master`. But beware, that's a very much different flow and merge conflicts are not fully avoidable at any time working with Git and multiple users.

Comment: You *don't* need a local `master` branch. You mention `egit` though, which apparently is something other than Git; perhaps egit itself insists on having a local `master`.

Answer (score 3):

Git doesn't know that commits have been made to master at origin unless you update the local repo somehow--usually either with a `fetch` or `pull`. This means that if you just merge your local copy of master you may be merging an obsolete head state, which can cause problems when you try to push.

You don't need a local master branch. You can avoid that hassle by merging the remote branch:

```
git merge origin/master
```

Answer (score 1):

I like this workflow which uses a combination of [`reset --hard`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) and [`rebase`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing):

1. Hard override local master with remote origin/master

```sh
git checkout master
git fetch --all
git reset --hard origin/master
```

2. Rebase current development branch to master. Note: Use rebase to avoid 'merge commits'.

```sh
git checkout feature
git rebase master
```

3. And yes, I do this all the time. Technically one could rebase directly to the origin/master, but I like to keep things in sync as much as possible.